# GPUImage locking view

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

In my application I have an object `CameraHandler` that uses GPUImage to detect certain movement from camera. It is initialized in my `GameViewController`.

It (`CameraHandler`) is able to successfully detect movements, and fire the relevant methods, however it locks up the `GameViewController`'s view for a significant amount of time (~5 to 10 seconds) before any of the changes are displayed on screen. Once the `CameraHandler` detects a change, it fires a method that changes the background of the top view on the view controller and displays a `UIAlertView` (for testing purposes). Like I said, this only happens after 5-10 seconds from the moment it is called. I know the program itself is not frozen because I get the relevant log outputs from the methods. I've tried different techniques to try and fix this but I have come out empty handed for several weeks now.

**In GameViewController (where I call and initiate the CameraHandler):**

```
-(void)startRound{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [_shotDetector captureStillImage];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"finish capture still image thread");

        });
    });
}

/* this method gets called from CameraHandler once it detects movement */
-(void)shotLifted:(NSNumber*)afterTime{
    NSLog(@"shot lifted fired");
    UIAlertView *lost = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Good Job!" message:@"Shot lifted in time" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [lost show];
    [_questionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSLog(@"shot lifted done");

}
```

**CameraHandler.h**

```
@interface CameraHandler : NSObject <GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate>

@property (strong) GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter,*emptyFilter;
@property (strong) GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera;
@property (strong) GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture;
@property (strong) GPUImageOutput *pictureOutput;
@property (strong) GPUImageStillCamera *stillCamera;
@property (strong) __block UILabel *shotRemovedLabel;
@property (strong) __block NSDate *startTime;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *averageLum;
@property (strong) id delegate;
@property (strong) GPUImageLuminosity *lumin;
```

**CameraHandler.m** - relevant method

```
-(void)startBlackoutShotMotionAnalysis{
    NSLog(@"starting shot motion analysis");


    [_videoCamera addTarget:self.filter];
    [_sourcePicture processImage];
    [_sourcePicture addTarget:self.filter];
    [_videoCamera startCameraCapture];

    _lumin = [[GPUImageLuminosity alloc] init];
    [self.filter addTarget:_lumin];

    __block int i =0;
     __unsafe_unretained GameViewController* weakDelegate = self.delegate;
    //begin luminosity detecting of live-video from uiimage
    [(GPUImageLuminosity *)_lumin setLuminosityProcessingFinishedBlock:^(CGFloat luminosity, CMTime frameTime) {
        if(i<60){
            if(i>10){
                _startTime = [NSDate date];
                [_averageLum addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:luminosity]];
            }
            i++;
        }
        else{
            CGFloat average = [[_averageLum valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.floatValue"]floatValue];
            CGFloat difference = fabsf(luminosity-average);

            if(difference > 0.05){
                NSTimeInterval liftedAfter = [_startTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
                [weakDelegate performSelector:@selector(shotLifted:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:liftedAfter]];
                [_videoCamera stopCameraCapture];
                NSLog(@"should turn white now");                    
                return ;
            }
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"finished returning executing starBlackoutMotionAnalysis Method");
}
```

NSLOG OUTPUT:

```
2014-04-08 20:22:45.450 Groupy[2887:5c0f] starting shot motion analysis
2014-04-08 20:22:46.152 Groupy[2887:5c0f] finished returning executing starBlackoutMotionAnalysis Method
2014-04-08 20:22:48.160 Groupy[2887:1303] shot lifted fired
2014-04-08 20:22:48.221 Groupy[2887:1303] shot lifted done
2014-04-08 20:22:48.290 Groupy[2887:1303] should turn white now
```

Any help in the right direction would be huge. I've been struggling with figuring this out.Thanks!

Comment: The docs for [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureSession/stopRunning) are fairly explicit about the camera hardware needing to spin down completely before control returns to you.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I usually look for when I see unusually delayed updates in the UI is whether or not my UI updating code is being executed on the main queue. Apart from a few exceptions, you should always dispatch any UI-related code to the main queue, or you'll get weird behaviour like this.

From what I can see, you perform the `shotLifted:` selector directly from within the `luminosityProcessingFinishedBlock`. We can safely assume that GPUImage will be calling that block off the main thread. This means that your code to initialise and show the alert view is happening off the main thread too.

To change this, you should try wrapping your call to `shotLifted:` in a block and dispatch that to the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakDelegate performSelector:@selector(shotLifted:) withObject:obj];
}
```

Or alternatively you can do:

```
[weakDelegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(shotLifted:) withObject:obj waitUntilDone:NO];
```